# Генерация чисел в html

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать генерацию случайных чисел при обновлении страницы?
Есть такое поле:

```
<div class="checkout-billing-content-field checkout-billing-content-total">
  <div class="checkout-billing-content-title">
    <span>Примечание</span>
  </div>
  <div class="checkout-billing-content-amount">
    <span class="checkout-currency">
      <input type="text" class="input-text" onclick="$(this).select();" style="margin-right: 50px;" readonly value="bill[mnkOmfrNCJROaRw]"> - вместо этих символов нужна генерация случайных чисел
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Геннирирует 15ти значное число

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('input-text')[0].value= "bill[" + parseInt(Math.random() * 1000000000000000) + "]";
```

```html
<div class="checkout-billing-content-field checkout-billing-content-total">
  <div class="checkout-billing-content-title">
    <span>Примечание</span>
  </div>
  <div class="checkout-billing-content-amount">
    <span class="checkout-currency">
      <input type="text" class="input-text" style="margin-right: 50px;" readonly > - вместо этих символов нужна генерация случайных чисел
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Добовляем перед `</body>`

```
<script>
document.getElementsByClassName('input-text')[0].value= "bill[" + parseInt(Math.random() * 1000000000000000) + "]";
</script>
```

Comment: Отлично то что нужно, как теперь совместить все это? не могу понять

Comment: что именно совместить?

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName('input-text')[0].value= "bill[" + parseInt(Math.random() * 1000000000000000) + "]";

Comment: <div class="checkout-billing-content-field checkout-billing-content-total">
  <div class="checkout-billing-content-title">
    <span>Примечание</span>
  </div>
  <div class="checkout-billing-content-amount">
    <span class="checkout-currency">
      <input type="text" class="input-text" style="margin-right: 50px;" readonly > - вместо этих символов нужна генерация случайных чисел
    </span>
  </div>
</div>

Comment: совместить это
что бы работала в index.html

Comment: сейчас я вам все распишу в ответе

Comment: проверьте код надо добавить это перед  </body>

Comment: Все работает только не в нужном месте

Comment: в каком месте нужно покажите html

Comment: <div class="checkout-billing-content-field checkout-billing-content-total">
                              <div class="checkout-billing-content-title">
                                 <span>Кошелек</span>
                              </div>
                              <div class="checkout-billing-content-amount">
                                 <span class="checkout-currency">
                                 <input type="text" class="input-text" onclick="$(this).select();" style="margin-right: 50px;" readonly  value="R906413138882">
 </span>
 </div>
</div>

Comment: работает только в этом параметре

Comment: у меня в html два поля
Поле "Кошелек"
и 
Поле "Примечание"

так вот в поле кошелек значение меняется а в примечание нет
нужно наоборот

Comment: измините ноль на 1 в коде

Comment: Готово, все работает!!! Спасибо вам огромное вы очень помогли мне, давно мучал этот вопрос с генерацией чисел, не как не мог найти ответ!

Comment: я рад :) .......

Comment: А вы не могли бы помочь с еще одной проблемой ,

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/618776/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0-e-mail-%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2?

Comment: щас гляну......

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
  var text = "";
  var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

  for(var i=0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
  }
  
  $(".input-text").val("bill[" + text + "]");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkout-billing-content-field checkout-billing-content-total">
  <div class="checkout-billing-content-title">
    <span>Примечание</span>
  </div>
  <div class="checkout-billing-content-amount">
    <span class="checkout-currency">
      <input type="text" class="input-text" onclick="$(this).select();" style="margin-right: 50px;" readonly value="bil[mnkOmfrNCJROaRw]">
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Для такого существует `Math.random`. Генерируете случайное число, а потом ставите нужное вам значение

```js
(function() {
  var num = Math.round((Math.random() * 100) * (Math.random() * 100));
  document.querySelector('.input-text').value = 'bill['+num+']';
})();
```

```html
<div class="checkout-billing-content-field checkout-billing-content-total">
  <div class="checkout-billing-content-title">
    <span>Примечание</span>
  </div>
  <div class="checkout-billing-content-amount">
    <span class="checkout-currency">
      <input type="text" class="input-text" onclick="$(this).select();" style="margin-right: 50px;" readonly value="bill[]">
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```