# Форма E-mail и "защита от дураков"

Tags: html, html-form

Доброго времени суток!

есть такая форма ввода и проверки e-mail

```
<body>
  <form>
   <p>Email: <input type="email" name="email" required></p>
   <p><input type="submit" value="Отправить"></p>
  </form>
 </body>
```

при нажатии на Enter форма показывает что заполнено не правильно и проверяет есть ли символ @

есть такая кнопка
открытие модального окна

```
<label class="btn" for="modal-2">Перейти к оплате</label>
```

задача: связать кнопку с формой e-mail
что бы был такой же эффект как при нажатии Enter
ну если все правильно кнопка переходила к модальному окну

Comment: Переход к оплате предполагает отправку формы или только валидацию?

Comment: Только валидацию

Comment: и переход к модальному окну

Comment: Знающие подскажите как поправить код ?

Comment: где модальное окно?

Comment: В выводе модального окна можно вызвать getElementById('form').reportValidity() он как раз показывает стандартный попап валидации html5 но работает не во всех браузерах.

Comment: Вот модальное окно

Comment: <div class="modal">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/modal.css" />
  <input class="modal-open" id="modal-2" type="checkbox" hidden>
  <div class="modal-wrap" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">
    <label class="modal-overlay" for="modal-2"></label>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h2>Выберите способ оплаты </h2>
        <label class="btn-close" for="modal-2" aria-hidden="true">×</label>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

Comment: Talleyran, можно подробнее ??

Comment: @Максим как у вас выглядит скрипт клика по кнопке <label class="btn" for="modal-2">?

Comment: Не как не могу разобраться, помогите

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. В общем случае, когда модальное окно выводится скриптом**

```js
$('.btn').click(function(){
      var myForm = $('#myForm');
      if (myForm[0].checkValidity()) { 
        alert("Я - модальное окно"); //тут должен быть ваш вызов модального окна
      } else {
        myForm[0].reportValidity();
      }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <form id="myForm">
   <p>Email: <input type="email" name="email" required></p>
   <p><input type="submit" value="Отправить"></p>
   <label class="btn" for="modal-2">Перейти к оплате</label>
  </form>
 </body>
```

**2. Частный случай автора, когда модальное окно выводится css через состояние чекбокса**

Форме присваиваем id

```
<form id="myForm">
```

На кнопке пишем onclick

```
<label for="modal-2" class="btn" onclick="check(this,'myForm'); return false">Перейти к оплате</label>
```

И перед `</body>` вставляем скрипт:

```
<script>
    function check(e, f) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var modal = document.getElementById(e.getAttribute('for'));
        var form = document.getElementById(f);

        if (form.checkValidity()) {
            modal.checked = true;
        } else {
            myForm[0].reportValidity();
            modal.checked = false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: уже лучше
подскажите куда вставлять этот код

Comment: $('.btn').click(function(){
      var myForm = $('#myForm');
      if (myForm[0].checkValidity()) { 
        alert("Я - модальное окно");
      } else {
        myForm[0].reportValidity();
      }
});

Comment: между какими то тегами ? или еще что?

Comment: @Максим это пример кода, вместо alert("Я - модальное окно"); должен быть Ваш вызов модального окна. Я не знаю, как он у вас реализован.

Comment: не понимаю
вот модальное окно

Comment: <div class="modal">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/modal.css" />
  <input class="modal-open" id="modal-2" type="checkbox" hidden>
  <div class="modal-wrap" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">
    <label class="modal-overlay" for="modal-2"></label>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h2>Выберите способ оплаты </h2>
        <label class="btn-close" for="modal-2" aria-hidden="true">×</label>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

Comment: вот кнопка его открытия

Comment: <label class="btn" for="modal-2">Перейти к оплате</label>

Comment: Пожауйста подскажите.

Comment: Последний штрих остался с этой функцией и сайт готов
а как сделать не знаю

Comment: @Максим каким образом выводится модальное окно? Какую библиотеку, плагин или самописный javascript вы для этого используете? Оно не может появляться на чистом html.

Comment: http://dbmast.ru/modalnoe-okno-na-html5-css3-i-skrytyh-chekboksah

Comment: модальное окно брал отсюда

Comment: Не как не могу разобраться, помогите

Comment: Отлично все работает!
Спасибо огромное добрый человек)